# When reading a string value and closing the COM object, the value sometimes gets invalid

Tags: excel, vbscript, com

**Short Description**

When I read a value from Excel the value is sometimes invalid. Could you please give a detailed explanation of what is
going on exactly?

**Detailed Description**

I read the value of the cell A1 and store it in `s` and the dictionary oDict. Depending on whether
I close Excel (`oExcel.Quit`) the value in the dictionary seems to become invalid (and `VarType` reports `vbObject` instead
of `vbString`).

When I replace the stored value with either version B or version C, the value seems to be copied (?) and the final VarType now reports `vbString`.

I appreciate a detailed explanation of why this is exactly.

Thank you for your consideration.

**Minimal test case**

(requires an excel file with a value at cell A1)

```
Option Explicit

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Temp\Excel.xlsx"

Dim oWorkSheet
Set oWorkSheet = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim s
s = oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1)

Dim oDict
Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

oDict.Add 1, oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1)           ' version A
'oDict.Add 1, ""&oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1)       ' version B
'oDict.Add 1, CStr(oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1))    ' version C

WScript.Echo VarType(s) & ", " & VarType(oDict(1)) ' prints 8 (vbString), 8 (vbString)

oExcel.Workbooks(1).Close
oExcel.Quit

WScript.Echo VarType(s) & ", " & VarType(oDict(1)) ' prints 8 (vbString), 9 (vbObject)
```

**References**

- [VarType](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_vartype.asp)

Comment: You are a victim of the *default property*.  Your "s" variable stores Range.Value since you didn't use Set.  And got a *copy* of the string.  Your dictionary however stores Range.  Which became invalid after you called Quit.  If you use Set s = oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) then they should misbehave the same way.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I am still confused though: The `Woorksheet.Cells` documentation says: "Item is the default property for the Range object". Therefore I assume `oWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1)` is actually `oWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1)`. However `Item` again returns a `Range`. How does `Value` enter the party?. (And: Is there a way to see the default property of an object? (I could not find anything in the docs of `Range` except the statement on `Worksheet.Cells`.))